# Can Pets' Attacks Crit?

Tags: league-of-legends

Simply put, do pets have the chance to crit when they attack? If so, would the critical damage be improved by Infinity Edge if bought?

Comment: upvoted as i have no clue and think this is a good question, though if i had to venture a guess i would say no

Comment: My guess is, pets as annies bear, malz voidling (gets AD and Magic resist). Those won't crit, but the pets as like Yoricks ghost, Mords pet and Shaco's clone do get crit over from the champions they mimick. Shaco's clone being Shaco... and the others being any champion. Same as attack speed, if mord kills and gets the ghost of an ad yi, that ghost will keep the attack speed and such yi had.

Comment: I would recommend narrowing down the question to a specific type of pet, whether it is clone/pet/turret and what have you, otherwise the answers people give could technically be true and false at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I have done some research now manually. I have gone into custom games and built up a full crit build, then when I have roughly 75% crit chance I used the pet only to see if it dealt any crits. Very few of the 'pets' gains crit from the owners critchance. 
**The real question is not whenever or not the pets crit, but if they GAIN crit from the champion.**

Malzahar's voidlings doesn't get crit from Malzahar, they gain AD from him though.

Shaco's boxes doesn't gain crit from Shaco, but his clone does. Infinity Edge works as well.

Annie's Tibbers, doesn't gain crit, he scales in power through Annie getting more AP.

Elise spiders doesn't gain crit, they gain power through Elise getting more AP.

Yorick's ghouls doesn't gain crit, they gain from AD and Health. Yorick's ghost doesn't gain crit from Yorick, but from whoever he clones it gains same items as, and thus gain crit chance that way.

Mordekaiser's ghost crit chance is only influenced by victims items, not by Mordekaiser. Even if Mordekaiser gains crit chance that doesn't transfer. The ghost gets stronger with Morde gaining AD, AP and Health though.

Zyra's plants doesn't gain increased crit chance with Zyra getting it. They get stronger with her getting AP.

LeBlanc's clone doesn't deal damage and cannot crit, the clone does utilize LeBlanc's on-hit effects though, and deal damage that way.

Answer (score 3):

I do not think so due to the fact that it is its own entity that does not share your stats, with the exception of shaco's clone, from what I have read it appears to duplicate all on hit effects including life steal and crits

Comment: sorry to tell you, but i have seen JitB's crit. do they count as pet? also i'd say morde-ult-pets can crit, just like yorick-ult-pets

Comment: how is it even possible for a jack in the box to crit? i thought that they were purely magic damage?

Comment: @Ravekner the funny thing is, these things count as autoatacks. even if they are magic damage only, they are not apllied as dot, but as on-hit. and thus they will crit(with a chance of < 1% it think)

Comment: @Vogel612 if the jack in the box damage is applied as on hit, would it not be far more probable that the Shaco had an item that procced with on hit effects and these effects carried over to said jack in the boxes? Effectively increasing the damage they would do normally.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to say no. As defined:

> A pet is a minion only responsive to a Champion of the League. They
>   either fulfill a specific part of an ability, a characteristic and
>   visual effects. Some pets have their own health, some are
>   controllable, some are static and some help cast abilities.

Comment: Just pointing this out, not saying your wrong, but the example you provided doesn't prove/disprove anything. It's just a definition of what a pet is, not what they are capable of.